# JSON - accessing value and looping

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

on form submit i am making an AJAX request to PHP code, in response this is what i get.

```
var data = {
    "empty":{
        "game_sais_no":"Season cannot contain empty value",
        "game_sc_no":"Category cannot contain empty value",
        "game_st_no2":"Visiting team connot contain empty value",
        "game_room_no_2":"Visiting room cannot contain empty value",
        "game_room_no_1":"Local chamber cannot contain empty value",
        "game_date":"Game date should be specified",
        "game_time":"Game time should be specified",
        "game_time_start":"Game start time should be specified",
        "game_time_close":"Game close time should be specified",
        "game_place_no":"Arena \/ Lot should be specified",
        "game_status":"Game status should be specified"
    }
}
```

**1**. i want to access single value. i tried accessing it like this.

```
data.empty.game_sais_no it returns me the value of undefined.
```

**2**. i want to loop through the json object and display all the messages back to the user. i tried using

```
$.each(data, function(index, value)(){
     //build the markup.
});
```

this is giving me unexpected result. where am i going wrong?

**UPDATE :** 
i am not sure but for some reason it is giving me weird result, let me show you what exactly i am doing.

here is my ajax call to php.

```
$('#gce_game_btn').on('click', function(){
    var formData = $('#gce_game_form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type    : 'POST',
        url     : 'accueil.php?m=ajax&game=1',
        data    : formData,
        success : function(data) {
            //
        }
    });
});
```

here is the array which i am trying to send back.

```
Array
(
    [empty] => Array
        (
            [game_sais_no] => Season cannot contain empty value
            [game_sc_no] => Category cannot contain empty value
            [game_st_no2] => Visiting team connot contain empty value
            [game_room_no_2] => Visiting room cannot contain empty value
            [game_room_no_1] => Local chamber cannot contain empty value
            [game_date] => Game date should be specified
            [game_time] => Game time should be specified
            [game_time_start] => Game start time should be specified
            [game_time_close] => Game close time should be specified
            [game_place_no] => Arena / Lot should be specified
            [game_status] => Game status should be specified
        )

)
```

i am using `json_encode()` and echoing it back. which in turn gives me this as string.

```
{
    "empty":{
        "game_sais_no":"Season cannot contain empty value",
        "game_sc_no":"Category cannot contain empty value",
        "game_st_no2":"Visiting team connot contain empty value",
        "game_room_no_2":"Visiting room cannot contain empty value",
        "game_room_no_1":"Local chamber cannot contain empty value",
        "game_date":"Game date should be specified",
        "game_time":"Game time should be specified",
        "game_time_start":"Game start time should be specified",
        "game_time_close":"Game close time should be specified",
        "game_place_no":"Arena \/ Lot should be specified",
        "game_status":"Game status should be specified"
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/juDFP/

Comment: never knew i could do it using for loop in javascript thank you. how about accessing single values.

Comment: `console.log(data.empty.game_sais_no);` works fine for me

Comment: `console.log(data.empty["game_status"]);` works fine

Comment: You are missing the dataType: 'json'  attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine. [Check the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tAfaQ/1/).

```
$.each(data, function(index, value){
    console.log(index);
    $.each(value, function(index, value) {
       console.log(index, value);
    });
});
​
```

Comment: it doesn't work for me, in my console it prints out every single variable. is there anything wrong since the data is response receieved `success : function(data) { // }`

Comment: @lbrahim Your code doesn't work doesn't mean my demo not work. Are you sure the `data` in your callback is an object, If it's string, you need to parse it to json, or set your ajax's `dataType` to `json`.

Comment: i am not using dataType as json, updating my question hold on please.

Comment: @lbrahim Yes, then you should know what's the problem.

Comment: oh, so this was all happening because i was not defining the dataType and javascript was treating it as plain text not as JSON, thank you. it works fine now.

Comment: @xdazz I've modified the fiddle to show the errors in html div.

Comment: @lbrahim You could check it yourself in your callback function.

Answer (score 1):

First you response is not returned in array. it were, it should have look like. see the `[` and `]`

```
"empty":[{
        "game_sais_no":"Season cannot contain empty value",
        "game_sc_no":"Category cannot contain empty value",
        "game_st_no2":"Visiting team connot contain empty value",
        "game_room_no_2":"Visiting room cannot contain empty value",
        "game_room_no_1":"Local chamber cannot contain empty value",
        "game_date":"Game date should be specified",
        "game_time":"Game time should be specified",
        "game_time_start":"Game start time should be specified",
        "game_time_close":"Game close time should be specified",
        "game_place_no":"Arena \/ Lot should be specified",
        "game_status":"Game status should be specified"
    }]
```

then you would be reading as

```
$.each(response.empty, function(index) {
           alert(response.empty[index].game_sais_no);

        });
```

Comment: i don't want to access the single value, i just wanted to know what am i doing wrong.

Comment: i am directly using `json_encode()` from PHP to convert the array to json object. so you think i should instead echo back the one you are saying?

Comment: I meant to say, you are not getting array.. there must be something wrong on the server side

Comment: It is valid but not a collection

Answer (score 1):

DO you see any errors in the console section of browser ??
There is nothing wrong in the way you are trying to access the json object

Try this

```
$.each(data.empty, function(i,value){
        console.log(value);
    }) ;
```

Check [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/NfeMC/)

**UPDATED**

You seem to be missing the **dataType: 'json'**  attribute in your ajax request.. 
If you do not specify that it parses the data as a string

```
$.ajax({
        type    : 'POST',
        url     : 'accueil.php?m=ajax&game=1',
        data    : formData,
        dataType: 'json'
        success : function(data) {
            //
        }
    });
```